# View rotation notifications: why didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: doesn't get called?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm trying to detect any device orientation change so that I can update the views.

I want to update the views whether the orientation is portrait or landscape, so I implemented this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations.
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

I know that if I want to update the views to show properly for the current orientation, I will need to implement some of the following methods:

```
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
– willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
– willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

Now, the problem is that I don't understand why none of these methods get fired when I rotate the simulator.

I tried as well this piece of code:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

But still nothing. So I'm wondering, does the simulator fire rotation notifications?
If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: where did you implement this method?

Comment: Yes simulator send notification for rotation.

Comment: @Ishu: thanks for the info;

@Deepak: if you are referring to the method didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation, I implemented it in the .m file of my view controller; if you are talking about [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications], I did this in the viewDidLoad of the view controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quick summary,** change this:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

to this:

```
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

---

I'm sorry if I took somebody's time for a silly mistake of mine. I found out why the method `– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` would never get called. Something brought my attention to the navigation controller:

> Only the root view controller's willRotate method is being called. Most likely you have a strange hierarchy of view controllers.

I found these post in another forum and I had a look at the app delegate. My code was as follows:

```
CGRect bound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bound.size.width, bound.size.height)];
TestViewController *viewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController release];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The problem was that I was not setting any view controller for the window, but I was just adding a view. It was a mistake I did due to the hurry to test something. I had to fix the code like this:

```
CGRect bound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bound.size.width, bound.size.height)];
TestViewController *viewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
[viewController release];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 53):

You need to add notification observer something like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and add the method

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
      UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

       if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
      {
        NSLog(@"Landscape Left!");
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed - there does seem to be a general recommendation that [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation is more reliable [than UIDevice orientation] so people may want to use the former - I certainly am.

Comment: Note that in the code above, UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification should be a constant, not the actual value. It just happens that the value of the constant is UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification :-)

Comment: w/r/t statusBarOrientation versus currentDevice orientation, some quick tests on my part suggest that checking statusBarOrientation in this use-case actually returns the *previous* orientation, while currentDevice returns the current/new orientation. Also, CurrentDevice will include UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp and UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown, while statusBar never does.