# UIWebView Rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, rotation

I am using a UIWebView in my app and when I rotate my iPhone the webview rotates along with it, works just fine. However, you see the corners of the background view behind my webview as it rotates and it can look a little flickery when rotating.

So I went and tried Safari on my iPhone, using the same website and it different. In Safari if I rotate, its far smoother, I can also see it zooms slightly.

For example, I am on Apple's homepage in portrait mode, fully zoomed out to see the whole page. I rotate to landscape and the contents zooms, as far as I can observe this is why it looks smoother.

So, my question, how can I achieve this in my app?

I have played with the 'Scales Page To Fit' option but had no success.

*Currently:*
Rotating scales the webpage to fit the view. (Whole page is zoomed out to be seen).

*Required:*
When rotating, rather than rescaling the page, just let it zoom as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will help you, but you might find it useful to change the background color (or even background image) of the view behind your webview, which might mitigate your issue with seeing the corners.

Comment: This was the first thing I considered, but thats not really useful at all, seen as the background colour is completely dependant on what the website looks like. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @JoshKahane It's completely possible to use a small bit of javascript to determine the background color of a webpage, or even the URL of it's background image, which you could then set as the background color of your webview.

Comment: I was unaware, perhaps this is a possibility then! I'll look into that further.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found a solution yet... As an alternative you could try refreshing the webview, if you notice that the device has rotated, refresh webview and webkit should renderize it again, also play with the HTML meta viewport tag (initial zoom, scale, etc.) and CSS media queries to support different scales. As for the HTML document, try using *em*, and *pt* units in CSS rules.

```
//reload webview
[self.webView reload];
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111013/view-rotation-notifications-why-didrotatefrominterfaceorientation-doesnt-get) Orientation Notifications

hope this help in something