# Different portrait and landscape layouts

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to get a handle on layouts in Xcode. I can't seem to find an article that is written well enough for my feeble mind to follow. I have 10 years programming experience but just got into Objective-C. I need some tutorials on dealing with the different views. Seems like they would have put some better tools into developing for a device that rotates by design.

Here is my specific dilemma: The app loads in portrait view and has a few buttons down the side like this:

```
[Button]

[Button]

[Button]
```

However, when the device rotates, I would like the buttons to align horizontally like this:

```
[Button]    [Button]     [Button]
```

So does anyone have any advice or know of a tutorial to help me accomplish this and as well as get a better grasp of orientations?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for tutorials or other off-site resources are usually closed since they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. On the same note: questions asking for general advice on a larger topic tend to be too broad and also risk being closed for that reason. Try and be more specific with your question, add relevant information to help narrow it down: (are you using IB or doing layout in code? are you using auto layout? etc.) and show us what you have already tried (even if it didn't work out).

Comment: Also, it's "Xcode" and not "xCode". I've already edited your question but I saw that you used the same spelling in your profile ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question in this case is: You will have to do this programmatically, or put it in a UICollectionView. UICollectionViews are actually meant for displaying many items and not just three as in your case, so there is really just one thing left: do it in code!

In the viewController that is handling this part of your app you should run this line somewhere in your `viewDidLoad` or `init` methods:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector:@selector(didRotate:) 
                                      name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification                      
                                      object:nil];
```

This will call the method `- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification`

You could implement this method like this:

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
      UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

       if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
      {
        NSLog(@"Landscape Left!");
      }
}
```

And put your layout code after you found out which orientation the device has.

Credits:
I borrowed the code from this thread, Thx 
[View rotation notifications: why didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: doesn't get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111013/view-rotation-notifications-why-didrotatefrominterfaceorientation-doesnt-get)