# How to get a parent view to recognize rotation in subview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation

I have two viewcontrollers. When the user clicks a button, the parent vc uses presentviewcontroller to call the subview. The problem I am having is when the user rotates the iphone in the subview then closes it, the parent view does not fit the whole screen (it turns to landscape but only displays on half of the screen). Is there a way to let the parent vc know it needs to rotate when it happens in a subview?

Also note that the parent view rotates perfectly when the rotation takes place in its view.

Comment: What is your target iOs version, how do you specify desired orientations for both view controllers ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to this previous [question][1]: [View rotation notifications: why didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: doesn't get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111013/view-rotation-notifications-why-didrotatefrominterfaceorientation-doesnt-get)

But I am also a bit unclear about your terminology.  I think you're using sub-view to refer to a subordinate VC, rather than a subordinate in the View Hierarchy.

Since you have two VCs you need to make sure that rotation handling code is present for both, and that the handlers are receiving the notifications. I suggest putting in diagnostic code in the rotation handlers for both VCs to see which is being called, and when - that should give you enough information to solve the problem or at least to post a followup.